# Problems with Coda 2/CoffeeScript plugin

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, coda

Regarding plugin for Coda 2. I am having some problems making it work. I have written a small test program in CoffeeScript, but when i try to run and/or compile I get the following error message:

[image]

All settings/env. variables should be set correctly:

[image]

Do you have any idea as to what that may cause this issue? I have installed node using homebrew, and then coffee script via npm. All the shell variables have been verified, and I am able to run node from the command line and write scripts there. Also, when i go to settings and click on "About", I get the following:

[image]

Hope you can help.

Thank you and best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal, run the command:

```
which coffee
```

For me, this gave:

```
/usr/local/bin/coffee
```

So in the CoffeeScript Plug-In Settings, I set PATH to:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Then when I went to the About box, it showed the version of CoffeeScript that I have installed and the Run & Compile options then worked fine.